# How to solve Out of memory on a 19660816-byte allocation error in android?

Tags: android, bitmap, base64

I am converting a bitmap to base64 and getting Out of memory on a 19660816-byte allocation problem. Below is my code to endoce bitmap to base64,

> ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>                       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
>                       byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
>                       String encoded = Base64Class.encode(b);

and my Base64Class code below:

```
public class Base64Class{
private Base64Class()
{
    super();
}

/**
 *  Encode some data and return a String.
 */
public final static String encode(byte[] d)
{
    if (d == null) return null;
    byte data[] = new byte[d.length+2];
    System.arraycopy(d, 0, data, 0, d.length);
    byte dest[] = new byte[(data.length/3)*4];

    // 3-byte to 4-byte conversion
    for (int sidx = 0, didx=0; sidx < d.length; sidx += 3, didx += 4)
    {
        dest[didx]   = (byte) ((data[sidx] >>> 2) & 077);
        dest[didx+1] = (byte) ((data[sidx+1] >>> 4) & 017 |
                (data[sidx] << 4) & 077);
        dest[didx+2] = (byte) ((data[sidx+2] >>> 6) & 003 |
                (data[sidx+1] << 2) & 077);
        dest[didx+3] = (byte) (data[sidx+2] & 077);
    }

    // 0-63 to ascii printable conversion
    for (int idx = 0; idx <dest.length; idx++)
    {
        if (dest[idx] < 26)     dest[idx] = (byte)(dest[idx] + 'A');
        else if (dest[idx] < 52)  dest[idx] = (byte)(dest[idx] + 'a' - 26);
        else if (dest[idx] < 62)  dest[idx] = (byte)(dest[idx] + '0' - 52);
        else if (dest[idx] < 63)  dest[idx] = (byte)'+';
        else            dest[idx] = (byte)'/';
    }

    // add padding
    for (int idx = dest.length-1; idx > (d.length*4)/3; idx--)
    {
        dest[idx] = (byte)'=';
    }
    return new String(dest);
}

/**
 * Encode a String using Base64 using the default platform encoding
 **/
public final static String encode(String s) {
    return encode(s.getBytes());
}

/**
 *  Decode data and return bytes.
 */
public final static byte[] decode(String str)
{
    if (str == null)  return  null;
    byte data[] = str.getBytes();
    return decode(data);
}

/**
 *  Decode data and return bytes.  Assumes that the data passed
 *  in is ASCII text.
 */
public final static byte[] decode(byte[] data)
{
    int tail = data.length;
    while (data[tail-1] == '=')  tail--;
    byte dest[] = new byte[tail - data.length/4];

    // ascii printable to 0-63 conversion
    for (int idx = 0; idx <data.length; idx++)
    {
        if (data[idx] == '=')    data[idx] = 0;
        else if (data[idx] == '/') data[idx] = 63;
        else if (data[idx] == '+') data[idx] = 62;
        else if (data[idx] >= '0'  &&  data[idx] <= '9')
            data[idx] = (byte)(data[idx] - ('0' - 52));
        else if (data[idx] >= 'a'  &&  data[idx] <= 'z')
            data[idx] = (byte)(data[idx] - ('a' - 26));
        else if (data[idx] >= 'A'  &&  data[idx] <= 'Z')
            data[idx] = (byte)(data[idx] - 'A');
    }

    // 4-byte to 3-byte conversion
    int sidx, didx;
    for (sidx = 0, didx=0; didx < dest.length-2; sidx += 4, didx += 3)
    {
        dest[didx]   = (byte) ( ((data[sidx] << 2) & 255) |
                ((data[sidx+1] >>> 4) & 3) );
        dest[didx+1] = (byte) ( ((data[sidx+1] << 4) & 255) |
                ((data[sidx+2] >>> 2) & 017) );
        dest[didx+2] = (byte) ( ((data[sidx+2] << 6) & 255) |
                (data[sidx+3] & 077) );
    }
    if (didx < dest.length)
    {
        dest[didx]   = (byte) ( ((data[sidx] << 2) & 255) |
                ((data[sidx+1] >>> 4) & 3) );
    }
    if (++didx < dest.length)
    {
        dest[didx]   = (byte) ( ((data[sidx+1] << 4) & 255) |
                ((data[sidx+2] >>> 2) & 017) );
    }
    return dest;
}

/**
 *  A simple test that encodes and decodes the first commandline argument.
 */
public static final void main(String[] args)
{
    if (args.length != 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Usage: Base64 string");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    try
    {
        String e = Base64Class.encode(args[0].getBytes());
        String d = new String(Base64Class.decode(e));
        System.out.println("Input   = '" + args[0] + "'");
        System.out.println("Encoded = '" + e + "'");
        System.out.println("Decoded = '" + d + "'");
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your image is far too big to convert into base64 in memory. You are going to need to write out the base64 to a file or other stream, bytes at a time.

Comment: Are you recicling your bitmaps through your app(i.e: using `bitmap.recicle();` ?

Comment: \what size is the image?

Comment: @Simon Image size is 1.47MB

Comment: @Hackerman Yes, I m using it

Comment: @CommonsWare Could you please help me. how to make file of it and then to bytes

Comment: Not the file size, that's irrelevant, what size is the image in pixels?

Comment: @Simonn W:1920 H:2560

Comment: That needs 19MB of RAM to load, and it's loaded on the heap which on many devices is limited to 16MB.  Read about "large heap" and scaling images when you load.

Comment: @Simon is there any way to increase heap

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=android+large+heap

Comment: @Simon try this but this dose not work could you please suggest some other.

Comment: Does not work? That means nothing. Exactly what didn't work? http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html